# how to install node's file system in a vanilla project

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

simple setup:

[image: my project tree/setup]

I want to use the Node.js File-System to update the todos.json inside /js folder.

normally i use CLI's like Vue to setup a project and all works like a charm in the background.
This time is want to understand how i can manually add a module like the `fs` by myself.

At the moment my console tells me:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

when doing this: `const fs = require('file-system');`

Comment: It seems like you don't have node installed?

Comment: you cannot use server side technology on client side

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Client on node: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: But are you running this in a _browser_? That's the only explanation for getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. Because Node definitely knows what `require` is. Stop wasting your time, the `fs` module that gives access to the file system is for Node (server-side) only. Browsers will _never_ let you do that. They restrict access to the local file system for obvious security reasons.

Comment: node is a JS runtime. It allows you to run JavaScript programs directly, without a browser environment. You write the script, save it, then run it from a command line: `node myscript.js` So here JavaScript is like any other programming language, and it has of course access to the hard drive via the `fs` module. All this however is completely separate from anything that happens inside a browser's `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is possible to get implementations of `require` that run client-side, you can't use the Node `fs` module in the browser. It has a JavaScript API but isn't written in JavaScript, it really does *depend* on Node.js.

If you want to update a JSON file on your server from the browser, then you'll need to write a web service to do the update (and then make an HTTP request from the browser to the webserver … typically using Ajax).

In general, you should use a real database and not a JSON file too. That way you'll already have solutions to concurrency problems.